# in PHP, how do I dynamically refer to a variable name?

Tags: php, variables

Best to ask this with an example. I have a table with fields like ID, MeterA1, MeterA2, MeterA3, ReadingA1, ReadingA2, ReadingA3 etc. (I didn't set this table up so de-normalised before you ask).

Rather than check each field for a value, I want to create a variable variable based on an abbreviated array and access the fields via that. What is the right way as this doesn't work:

```
$array = array('A1', 'A2', 'A3');

while($row = $rec->fetch_object()) { // db record fetch
    foreach($array as $meter) {
        $result[$row->Meter{$meter}] = $row->Reading{$meter};
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of TFM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: `$row->{'Meter'.$meter}`

Comment: @deceze Of course its a duplicate thats where I got the above code from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array('A1', 'A2', 'A3');

while($row = $rec->fetch_object()) { // db record fetch
    foreach($array as $meter) {
        $key1 = "Meter{$meter}";
        $key2 = "Reading{$meter}";
        $result[$row->$key1] = $row->$key2;
    }
}
```